# I'm unable to set the error received from the json response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I'm getting a response (data.message) from a fetch as shown in the box below:

```
{email: Array(1), password: Array(1)}
   email: ['The email field is required.']
   password: ['The password field is required.']
```

This is my complete code:

```
const [error, setError] = useState();

const signUp = (event) => {
  fetch(`${api_urls.backend}/api/users/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: email.value, password: password.value }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if ((Object.entries(data.message)).length > 0) {
                    setError(Object.entries(data.message));
                    return;
                }
console.log(error);
};

return(
 <form className="sign-form" onSubmit={signUp}>
                <div className="sign-top"></div>
                <div className="sign-bottom"></div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="userMail">
                        Insert mail
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="userMail"
                        {...email}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="userPassword">
                        Insert password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="userPassword"
                        {...password}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-info px-5 rounded-0">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form >
)
```

I created a state named error to save this information in this state via setError.

I tried making Object.entries of data.message to convert it to an array and then use a map to print the errors into the view.

I noticed though that 'error' is always empty.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Where are you logging the entry ? Try logging it in the function body if you have tried just after setting state

Comment: Since I didn't understand you, I updated the code above to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `Boolean` state to describe there is an Error instead `Array` value

```
function Login() {

    const [isError, setError] = useState(false);
    const [EmailMessage, setEmailMessage] = useState(null);
    const [PasswordMessage, setPasswordMessage] = useState(null);

    const signUp = (event) => {
        fetch(`${api_urls.backend}/api/users/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: email.value, password: password.value }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if ((Object.entries(data.message)).length > 0) {
                    setError(true);
                    setEmailMessage(data.message.email[0]);
                    setPasswordMessage(data.message.password[0]);
                }
            })
            
    };

        return (
            <form className="sign-form" onSubmit={signUp}>
                <div className="sign-top"></div>
                <div className="sign-bottom"></div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="userMail">
                        Insert mail
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="userMail"
                        {...email}
                    />
                    {(isError && EmailMessage) && <span>{EmailMessage}</span>}  {/* You have to style the error message */}
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="userPassword">
                        Insert password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="userPassword"
                        {...password}
                    />
                    {(isError && PasswordMessage) && <span>{PasswordMessage}</span>}
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-info px-5 rounded-0">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form >
        )
}
```

Comment: How do I print errors in this case? even via a p tag!

Comment: let me change the code for that

Comment: I also updated the question code

Comment: I updated the code, Use the span element to display any message related to email and password. You have to style based on your ui.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't read isError outside of the function

Comment: What you tryed? Outside the function means, add the code

Comment: updated function. Added a return and a console.log